# How to pass empty variables to a function in Lua

Tags: variables, lua, function-parameter

I've tried to pass empty values to a function but failed. Here is my setup;

```
function gameBonus.new( x, y, kind, howFast )   -- constructor
    local newgameBonus = {
        x = x or 0,
        y = y or 0,
        kind = kind or "no kind",
        howFast = howFast or "no speed"
    }
    return setmetatable( newgameBonus, gameBonus_mt )
end
```

I want only to pass "kind" and want the constructor to handle the rest. Like;

```
 local dog3 = dog.new("" ,"" , "bonus","" )
```

Or I want only to pass "howFast";

```
 local dog3 = dog.new( , , , "faster")
```

I tried both with `""` and without, gives error:

> **unexpected symbol near ','**

Comment: is it me or do you call the wrong function? You call `dog.new` but the function is called `gameBones.new`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nil` is the type and value to represent empty in Lua, so instead of passing an empty string `""` or nothing, you should pass `nil` like this:

```
local dog3 = dog.new(nil ,nil , "bonus", nil )
```

Note that the last `nil` can be omitted.

Take the first parameter `x` as an example, the expression

```
x = x or 0
```

is equivalent to:

```
if not x then x = 0 end
```

That is, if `x` is neither `false` nor `nil`, sets `x` with the default value `0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function gameBonus.new( x, y, kind, howFast )   -- constructor
  local newgameBonus = type(x) ~= 'table' and 
    {x=x, y=y, kind=kind, howFast=howFast} or x
  newgameBonus.x = newgameBonus.x or 0
  newgameBonus.y = newgameBonus.y or 0
  newgameBonus.kind = newgameBonus.kind or "no kind"
  newgameBonus.howFast = newgameBonus.howFast or "no speed"
  return setmetatable( newgameBonus, gameBonus_mt )
end

-- Usage examples
local dog1 = dog.new(nil, nil, "bonus", nil)
local dog2 = dog.new{kind = "bonus"}
local dog3 = dog.new{howFast = "faster"}
```